# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: can't successfully load the class source

Tags: java, android, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I am working on an Android project - so far so good.
Today I added some extra Java code to the project - I will call it here calcCode. This is some code doing calculations in the background and is not Android specific - I will just be using it in my project.

I added that new code to a different package than my Android code under the same project.

So what I have is:

```
Project
 AndroidPackage
  AndroidCode
 SomeJaveCodePackage
  UtilityCode
```

For some reason, when I try to debug the calcCode I get this annoying source not found error. Still - the code runs and delivers the correct results as always. I took the calcCode from some other project and copied the files into my new Android project. When I couldn't see the source I deleted all the calcCode files and manually created them by first creating a class file under the relevant package and then copy-pasted the code in. I thought this will help Eclipse recognize the path of the classes.

I also tried to: "Edit Source Lookup Path" and add the source code of the class I was trying to debug.

This didn't change anything - I can still not debug the code. 
I read several answers to this issue on StackOverflow. Most deal with Junit and Tomcat and I followed their recommendations but it didn't change the situation.

Anyone knows why this is happening?

I have Eclipse Indigo.

---

EDITED after m0skit0's remarks:
Thank you m0skit0 for the help. I meant to ask only one question (I might have mixed up stuff on the way). My question is: Why can't Eclipse find my own code while I debug it. It used to work in a former project (that I was able to follow the code through all the app's course during debug).

What I do is set a break point at

```
Tour myTour = new Tour("res/raw/td.csv", "readCSV");
```

Tour is my own hand-made class. When I press F5 in order to step into it I get the error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException and in the code window I get Source not found and a button Edit source lookup path.

This is the call stack:

```
Thread [main] (Suspended)
    ClassNotFoundException(Throwable).<init>(String, Throwable) line: 286   
    ClassNotFoundException(Exception).<init>(String, Throwable) line: not available 
    ClassNotFoundException(ReflectiveOperationException).<init>(String, Throwable) line: not available  
    ClassNotFoundException.<init>(String) line: not available   
    URLClassLoader$1.run() line: not available  
    URLClassLoader$1.run() line: not available  
    AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]   
    Launcher$ExtClassLoader(URLClassLoader).findClass(String) line: not available   
    Launcher$ExtClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
    Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
    Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available  
    Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: not available  
    TestAllPlayAll.main(String[]) line: 15
```

Thanks,
D

Comment: You should paste in some of your error messages and maybe even some of the relevant code.  For example, maybe you think it is saying the error is in your code, but its actually some other class that called your code that has the error.  Also it seems like you are asking two questions, one about ClassNotFoundException and one about seeing code when you debug?  Good luck!

Comment: try a clean project abd buld again, sometime it helps. Also try to load again ( open and close the eclipse )

Comment: @preetha - what do you mean with "try a clean project abd buld again"? I tried to clean the project, refresh Eclipse, reload Eclipse and create a new project. Non of this helped. This seems to me to be some Eclipse issue and not a Java issue.

Comment: sorry for typo its "and bulid" not "abd build" . Is it only when you try to debug the issue is coming. Are you sure you are hitting this new code when you run normally ? you can try adding some logs in that code and make sure its getting hit. These might help you get a clue

Comment: Thanks @preetha. Yes - this happens only when I debug. In addition the code works and produces the needed result. I am quite sure I hit the right code. The debugger stops right before I create an object of my own. When I try to step in - the dbugger says it cannot find the source.

Comment: Could this have something to do with the fact that the class, which source is not found, is in a different package than the calling class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved. The sad thing is that I don't know the solution. What I did was simply to open a new project and use the code there. After I did this i could debug the code with no problem.

Sorry I couldn't contribute to REALLY solving this issue and help the community with the answer to my own question.

Thanks to all that tried to help,
D.